# Port A digital output set up on pic16lf1827

Tags: pic, adc, comparator, port

I am having difficulty moving my code from port b to port a on pic. I am looking at adc disabling and also comparator disabling, but not having much joy. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
void init_pic(void)
{
    //OSCCON = 0b01101000;

    TRISA<4:0>=0;   
    TRISB=0b00000000;       //set up for I2C and USART, plus ADC input on AN9 (RB3)
    ANSELA = 0b00000000;    //all digital outputs
    ANSELB = 0b00000000;    //all digital outputs
    ADCON0 = 0x0F;          // All digital inputs
    ADCON1 = 0x0F;          // All digital inputs

    CM1CON0 =0X07;
    LATA = 0b00000000;
}
```

Comment: What kind of compiler allows you to write this `TRISA<4:0>=0;` ?

Comment: xc8 shows no error,

Comment: Then why did you put it in your code? Replace it with some valid C code.

Comment: `TRISA &= 0b1110000;` should do what you want.

Comment: m.Alin no fix with that change im afraid,